# Struggling with a Complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, cubics

> Solve $f(z) = z$ for $$f(z)=\frac{iz-1}{(z+1)^2}, \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{-1\}.$$

I found that $i$ is a solution. However, the exercise says there are 2 more. I tried using the algebraic expression but it's harder, and used arguments and got nothing.

Comment: Please do not use images, they are not searchable.

Comment: Adding $f(z)-z$ gives you a fraction with a cubic polynomial in the numerator. If you already found that $z=i$ is a solution (it make that numerator vanish), then the numerator is divisible by $z-i$. When you divide you get a quadratic polynomial, which you can solve using the quadratic formula.

Comment: I feel so stupid after reading your answer, how could I forget something like that..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**
You have
$$
iz-1 = z(z+1)^2
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
p(z) = z^3+2z^2+(1-i)z + 1 = 0,
$$
which is indeed a cubic equation and should have exactly 3 complex roots. Since you know $z=i$ is a root, $q(z) = p(z)/(z-i)$ is a quadratic polynomial, so solving $q(z)=0$ will give you the other 2 roots.

Comment: Indeed, I have found the solutions, thank you!